# initialize firebase 3.4.0 in Vue.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm having some trouble connecting firebase 3.4.0 to my Vue.js App. I am relatively new to Vue.js, and there is very little documentation out there for connecting to firebase 3.0. Here is my main.js file, and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Firebase from 'firebase'

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyBew0KrZus-fa1mtQ8KOCk-i7FFMvR0qHM',
  authDomain: 'gkeep-180a7.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://gkeep-180a7.firebaseio.com',
  storageBucket: 'gkeep-180a7.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '573966307891'
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

firebase.database().ref('notes').set([
  {
    title: 'Hello World',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum'
  }
])

firebase.database().ref('notes').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let notes = snapshot.val()
  console.log(notes)
  window.alert(notes[0].title)
})
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

Here are the two general errors I get in my NPM terminal when I try to run the webpack dev server:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars  'Firebase' is defined but       never used
  C:\Users\nash_\Documents\keepClone\keep-clone\src\main.js:3:8
  import Firebase from 'firebase'
          ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef        'firebase' is not defined
  C:\Users\nash_\Documents\keepClone\keep-clone\src\main.js:13:1
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported Firebase but used firebase
-- notice the capital F

Either change the import to:
`import firebase from 'firebase';`

Or change all calls to `Firebase.initializeApp` or `Firebase.database()`